# Save CURL is output into a variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file, curl

Hi this is my first post so if I haven't formatted something correctly or am not on topic please let me know.

I need to use cURL to access a database and extract datapoints for each device stored in the cloud. My question thus far is how do I save the access token from this line:

```
`curl -X POST -d "<user><email>myemail@anexample.com</email><password>Passwordexample</password><application><app_id>anidexample_id</app_id><app_secret>asecretexample_secret</app_secret></application></user>" -H "Content-Type:application/xml" https://user.aylanetworks.com/users/sign_in.xml`
```

Into a variable.

So far I've used :

```
 @echo off
    set /p UserInput= Enter the Access Token:
    @echo on

    curl -H "Authorization: auth_token %UserInput%" https://ads-dev.aylanetworks.com/apiv1/dsns/AC000W000007000/properties.xml>TestFile.xml
```

This passes the token but it needs to be entered manually every time. I've tried to use set without needing user input and I haven't been able to get it working. Is there something that I'm missing with setting variables?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

DM

Comment: Between which <TAG></TAG> is the token ?

Comment: The command output looks like this:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<authorization>
  <access-token>0317080d361a430bb81e3997114267bf</access-token>
  <refresh-token>c696753bddb4459c9a8ceb54fa04d53b</refresh-token>
  <expires-in type="integer">86400</expires-in>
  <role>OEM::Staff</role>
  <role-tags type="array"/>
</authorization>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the CURL's XML response look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <authorization> 
   <access-token>0317080d361a430bb81e3997114267bf</access-token>
   <refresh-token>c696753bddb4459c9a8ceb54fa04d53b</refresh-token> 
   <expires-in type="integer">86400</expires-in> 
   <role>OEM::Staff</role> 
   <role-tags type="array"/> 
    </authorization>
```

You can try :

```
@echo off

set URL="<user><email>myemail@anexample.com</email><password>Passwordexample</password><application><app_id>anidexample_id</app_id><app_secret>asecretexample_secret</app_secret></application></user>"

for /f "skip=2 tokens=3 delims=^<^>" %%a in ('curl -X POST -d  %URL% -H "Content-Type:application/xml" https://user.aylanetworks.com/users/sign_in.xml') do (
  set "$token=%%a"
  goto:next)

:next
echo The token is : %$token%
pause
curl -H "Authorization: auth_token %$token%" https://ads-dev.aylanetworks.com/apiv1/dsns/AC000W000007000/properties.xml>TestFile.xml
```

I putted a `PAUSE` before sending the second request that you can check if there is a correct value in `%$token%`

Comment: Thank you that answer worked for me! I used something similar before and I am wondering why you wrote %%a instead of %a?

Comment: You use %a only when you run a command directly in the `CMD` in a `bat` file you have to double the %.

Comment: Oh I forgot about that rule! You're right that makes a huge difference. Thank you again I really appreciate the answer.